# Two separate $.ajax call "kill" each other on click function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So here is the problem:
I have two click event in one page. The first when you click on a thumbnail picture it's open a modal which shows a bigger image like Instagram on PC (I make an Instagram clone for practicing btw). The other button is for show more image.

The problem is, I use ajax for both click to get some variable and pass to the php. When the page loaded it's shows only 3 image and when I clicked one of them It's shows the right image in the modal but when I click show more it shows 3 more and after when I clicked on the thumbnail it's stucked. I mean its shows only one picture doesn't matter which thumbnail i clicked so the ajax request not runs again. I hope you can understand the problem and can help me. (sorry for my English).

So here is the code:

This is the ajax calling function:

```
function ajaxShow(urls,datas,element){
    $.ajax({
        url: urls,
        data: {datas: datas},
        cache:true,
    }).always(function(result){
        console.log("done");
        element.html(result);
    });
}
```

And these are the click events:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Open picture in modal
    var pic = $(".pics");
    var modalCont = $(".modal-content");

    pic.on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        console.log(id);
        ajaxShow("../php/ajax_modal.php",id,modalCont);
    });

    //Load more
    var smbt = $(".smbt");
    var limit = $(smbt).data('loaded');

    smbt.on('click',function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var cont = $("#cont");
        limit += 3;
        console.log(limit);
        ajaxShow("../php/show_more.php",limit,cont);
    });
});
```

In a nutshell: After I clicked on load more the modal open ajax request not run again.

Comment: you need to append click function to loaded content. on load the page js append click to loaded content, but after the click don't append this for new dynamical loaded content.

Comment: Thank you for responding!
Can you write it a little more specific or some example because im not really understand what I have to change or what to do.

Comment: I think you should use `unbind` event before every `on` one. Like `pic.unbind('click').bind('click', function(event){ event.preventDefault(); //etc  });` More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use overloaded version of `.on()` on `document` node.

```
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler );
```

So your code should be rewritten as this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pics', null, function (event) {   
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log(id);
    ajaxShow("../php/ajax_modal.php",id,modalCont);
});
```

and

```
$(document).on('click', '.smbt', null, function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var cont = $("#cont");
    limit += 3;
    console.log(limit);
    ajaxShow("../php/show_more.php",limit,cont);
});
```

Comment: live() is removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: jQuery version 2.2.4